# Nth-child applying to every button

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to perform different styling on every other button using the following css:

```
tr td:nth-child(odd) button {
   background-color: red;
}
```

However, every single button is red, and they all have the same tr td:nth-child(odd) button {} styling on them.
These buttons are being "created" within a g:each statement:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<g:each in="${exactMatches}">
 <tr>
   <td>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal${it.id}">
        ${it.name}
    </button>
    .
    . more stuff that appears in modal...
    .
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repeater is creating a structure like this (apparently):

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <button></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button></button>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

So, the `nth-child` selector should be on the `tr` element, because there's only one `td` on each tr:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td button {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all your buttons inside one TD, so you need to change your css to:

```
tr td button:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Zav That did not work, I updated my code to show the structure a little more

Comment: Also try just for test - background-color: red !important;

Comment: what do you mean by "compiled" html, and !important made no difference.

Comment: compiled = rendered in browser. If you use firefox you can use plugin "web developer" -> view source -> view generated source

Comment: I use google chrome and I can view the source. It is rather long so how should I put it on here?

Comment: No, just related part: the table. Put it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and provide link here.

Answer (score 0):

remove button in css

```
td button:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: red;//whatever colr
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use button:nth-child(2)??

Comment: Still all buttons are red

Comment: button:nth-child(2) will not even work for me at all

Comment: is it possible to add all your css html and js in jsfiddle or relevant code so i can test it properly. also URL might help.

Comment: I have never used jsfiddle before. The piece of html is a template that is being rendered also, so Im not sure if it would work out. Also my javascript function does an ajax call to a controller action, that then uses services I have set up to obtain the results.